# Does anyone know whether DOLS will support xPages anytime soon?

Tags: xpages

Does anyone know whether DOLS are going to support xPages anytime soon? I saw these notes from 2010 but cant find any up-to-date information.

https://www-304.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21389133

... or here ...

http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/nd85forum.nsf/5f27803bba85d8e285256bf10054620d/4f71ab2004085d4485257487006681cc?OpenDocument&Highlight=0,dols

Comment: DOLS is a Domino server feature. This question might be better on serverfault.com

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The situation hasn't changed, there currently no plan to get XPages support for DOLS. It is a logged feature request and it maybe something that will be addressed in the future.